# Unable to load DICOM images using Pydicom inside tf.data.Dataset

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, pydicom, medical-imaging

I'm trying to make a data generator to load DICOM images in batches to use in model.fit using Tensorflow:

```py
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_names, annotations))

dataset = dataset.map(find_path, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.map(read_dicom, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.map(augment_images, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.map(resize_images, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.map(normalize_bbox, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.batch(64, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

- The first function (`find_path`) convert file name to path.
- The second function (`read_dicom`) tries to load dicom images, it's something like this:

  ```py
  from pydicom import dcmread
  ...

  def read_dicom(path, annotation):
      raw_dicom = dcmread(path)
      image = dcm.pixel_data_handlers.util.apply_voi_lut(raw_dicom.pixel_array, raw_dicom)

      return image, annotation
  ```

---

I get an error in `dcmread(path)` which say:

```
TypeError: dcmread: Expected a file path or a file-like, but got SymbolicTensor
```

I don't completely understand the situation but from what i know the reason for this is that when `model.fit` running in graph mode, converts every function into graph. This makes every variables coming into functions `SymbolicTensor` hence paths are `SymbolicTensor` and can't be used with Pydicom or any other library.

---

I tried multiple methods to fix this problem but they ether not working or they are not suitable for the project i'm doing:

1. using `tf.py_function` to prevent tensorflow from converting `read_dicom` into graph

   This method works but is not usable for me because i want to use Tensorflow threading to load multiple images simultaneously. if i use `tf.py_function` it runs python code which has GIL and prevent threads from running at the same time.
2. using `Tensorflow IO` library to load the image

   ```py
   import tensorflow as tf
   import tensorflow_io as tfio
   ...

   def read_dicom(path, annotation):
      raw_image = tf.io.read_file(path)
      image = tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(raw_image)

      return image, annotation
   ```

   This method doesn't work as the `tfio.image.decode_dicom_image` in `Tensorflow IO` library does not work. You can check out the colab notebook which tensorflow provided in a dicom tutorial, it doesn't work there too!

   https://www.tensorflow.org/io/tutorials/dicom
   https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/io/blob/master/docs/tutorials/dicom.ipynb

I should note that i want to use tensorflow built-in multithreading.

Do you have any idea how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually `tfio.image.decode_dicom_image` works. You only need to ensure `tensorflow-io` is compatible with your `tensorflow` version. See the markdown [from here](https://github.com/tensorflow/io#tensorflow-version-compatibility).

Test run:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

file_name = np.array(['dicom_00000001_000.dcm'])
annotation = np.array([1])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((file_name, annotation))

def read_dicom(path, annotation):
   raw_image = tf.io.read_file(path)
   image = tfio.image.decode_dicom_image(raw_image)

   return image, annotation

dataset = dataset.map(read_dicom)

for x, y in dataset:
    plt.imshow(x.numpy().squeeze(), cmap='gray')
```

Gives the image that is used in the tutorial:
[image]